# Find linear time algorithm to find element which is smallest of its neigbours in 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n * n , give an O(n) algorithm to find out pair of indices `i` and `j` such that `A[i][j] < A[i-1][j]` ,`A[i][j] < A[i+1][j]` ,`A[i][j] < A[i][j-1]` and `A[i][j] < A[i][j+1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible, unless there are further constraints we haven't been told about. Each position you investigate can rule out/verify at most 5 positions, so by looking at `k` positions (and their neighbours) you can rule out/verify at most `5*k` positions.

Comment: No, it isn't impossible.  There is a divide-and-conquer algorithm.

Comment: I'm curious. How would that work?

Comment: @han If there is a divide and conquer algorithm to solve this without looking at all the elements, I'd really like to see it. Until then I'm quite sure that no such algorithm exists and solving the problem as specified is in fact impossible.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Looking at the OP's post again, I must concede that as specified, there is no appropriate algorithm: The proper counterexample is to set all elements except one equal.  However, if equal elements are forbidden, or if the inequality conditions are made nonstrict (`A[i][j] <= A[i-1][j]` etc.) then divide-and-conquer works.  See [here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/lectures/lec02.pdf)

Comment: @han Ah, yes, with non-strict inequalities, divide-and-conquer is possible - I didn't know that you can apparently make that linear and not O(n*log n).

Comment: I'm curious now, what would the divide and conquer approach be?

Comment: @Clément There's a link in han's second comment (two above yours) where it's explained.